# Can you help me know what does "カンジ" means?

Tags: meaning, translation, words, slang, word-requests

I came across a drawing tutorial about colouring eyes on pixiv. And there is this sentence:

> こんなカンジの目を描きたい人向け。

I know カンジ reads as "Kanji". But if you put in the sentence and the content about drawing eyes tutorial, it is a bit off and I haven't found the correct meaning. And I also saw it re-used in the sentence:

> 色まぜペンでイイカンジにします。

So I wonder if this was a Japanese slang for something and how do I translate it? I have to translate that page but I don't have the contact to the artist.

Comment: As an aside, it doesn't seem likely to me that a randomly selected Japanese artist on Pixiv will either know enough English to communicate with you, nor have any interest in helping you with an English translation of anything. (And if you could ask about it in Japanese, then you wouldn't have the question.)

Answer (score 1):

> So I wonder if this was a Japanese slang for something and how do I translate it?

Perhaps you read "kanji" (or かんじ in hiragana, or カンジ in katakana), and only think of 漢字 - i.e., the name for the fancy characters the textbook is making you slowly and painfully memorize.

However, another common word with the same pronunciation is 感じ, which Jisho glosses as "feeling; sense; impression​". In the two contexts you've highlighted - after こんな and after いい - the intended word will almost always be 感じ, because these are common idioms.

「いい感じ」, literally a "good feeling", carries a sense of comfort or ease or pleasantness.

```
色     まぜ   ペン で         イイ カンジ  に      します。

colour+mixing+pen by-means-of good feeling towards is-done

"By using a (???) pen, we/I make [it] nice [to look at]."
```

(I suspect that 色まぜペン is a specific term with a specific meaning, but search results don't seem very helpful. From the photos, it might just be that they're pens with ink that's selected for pleasant colour blending. Or if the context is digital art, maybe this refers to a specific tool in the drawing program?)

「こんな感じ」, literally "this kind of feeling", is usually better translated as "like this" or similar. It's often used by itself, as an implied question ("This way? Am I doing it right?").

```
こんなカンジの           目  を           描き    たい  人     向け。

this  way   -categorized eye (accusative) drawing -want person -intended-for

"For those who want to draw eyes [that look] like this."
```

The word 感じ is not at all slang, but it is used in some colloquialisms; and the choice here to use katakana is definitely for a specific stylistic effect. Because the text seems to be about drawing faces, I guess that the author wants to emphasize the idea of a cool, in-vogue appearance created by drawing with specific techniques.